# C recursive header file inclusion problem?

Tags: c, recursion, header, include

Suppose you have to related structures defined in 2 header files like below:

a.h contents:

```
#include b.h

typedef struct A
{
  B *b;
} A;
```

b.h contents:

```
#include a.h

typedef struct B
{
  A *a;
} B;
```

In such this case, this recursive inclusion is a problem, but 2 structures must point to other structure, how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google C/C++ guidelines suggests](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5FQoJdw1sdRVHRid21IalRRb3M/edit?resourcekey=0-0OIuS0JpAEz34vYFETmWUQ):

> Don't use an #include when a forward declaration would suffice

That'd mean:

a.h contents:

```
typedef struct B B;

typedef struct A
{
  B *b;
} A;
```

b.h contents:

```
typedef struct A A;

typedef struct B
{
  A *a;
} B;
```

---

If you prefer something a bit safer (but longer to compile) you can do this:

a.h contents:

```
#pragma once
typedef struct A A;

#include "B.h"

typedef struct A
{
  B *b;
} A;
```

b.h contents:

```
#pragma once
typedef struct B B;

#include "A.h"

typedef struct B
{
  A *a;
} B;
```

Comment: Just for my curiosity, what is `#pragma once`?

Comment: It's the new way (supported by pretty much any compiler) of doing `#ifndef MY_HEADER_H__ #define MY_HEADER_H__ ... #endif`. It means that if you have #include "foo.h" twice and foo.h has `#pragam once`, it'll only apply the declarations once. Else you'd have a compilation error.

Answer (score 5):

Don't #include a.h and b.h, just forward-declare A and B.

a.h:

```
struct B; //forward declaration
typedef struct A
{
    struct B * b;
} A;
```

b.h:

```
struct A; //forward declaration
typedef struct B
{
    struct A * a;
} B;
```

You might want to think about how tightly coupled the classes are. If they're very tightly coupled, then maybe they belong in the same header.

Note: you'll need to `#include` both a.h and b.h in the `.c` files to do things like `a->b->a`.

Answer (score 2):

You pre-define the struct only, in that way you can still declare a pointer:

In `a.h`:

```
typedef struct B_ B;

typedef struct A_
{
  B *b;
} A;
```

Note how I use separate names for the `typedef` and struct tags, to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This will cut it in C:

```
typedef struct B B;
typedef struct A A;
struct A { B *b; };
struct B { A *a; };
```

You can rearrange `B` and `A` as desired.