# Calling member functions on a parent object?

Tags: c++, class, superclass

I have two classes : `World`, and `Entity`.

Inside of World I have two Entity pointers which I made like so:

```
Entity* ent1;
Entity* ent2;
```

I wanted to allow Entity objects to call World's public member functions.
I thought was that I could simply pass in a reference or a pointer of World to the Entity.

But when I include `World.h` from `Entity.h`, I start getting errors.
It does seem a bit wrong as they include each other but I have no other idea of how to achieve this functionality.

In other programming languages I've seen the *parent* keyword, is there anything like that in C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular C++ Header Includes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281641/circular-c-header-includes)

Comment: Probably you will need to do a forwad declaration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration

Comment: Since you are using pointers, you don't need to include the `World` class header in `entity.h`, you only need to do a forward declaration: `class World;`.

Comment: what errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward-declare class `Entity` in *World.h*.

**World.h:**

```
class Entity; // #include "Entity.h" is not needed, because
              // only a pointer to Entity is used at the moment.

class World {
  public:
    void foo() {}

    void letEntityDoFooToMe(); // Implementation must be defined later, because it
                               // will use the whole Entity class, not just a
                               // pointer to it.
  private:
    Entity* e;
};
```

**Entity.h:**

```
#include "World.h" // Needed because Entity::doFooToWorld calls a method of World.

class Entity {
  public:
    Entity(World& world) : w(world) {}

    void doFooToWorld() {
      w.foo();
    }

  private:
    World& w;  
};
```

**World.cpp:**

```
#include "World.h"  // Needed because we define a method of World.
#include "Entity.h" // Needed because the method calls a method of Entity.

void World::letEntityDoFooToMe() {
  e->doFooToWorld();
}
```

Comment: I see, but this case limits World right? As in, World won't be able to call Entity's public methods.. is there a way to change that?

Comment: @Don I added method `World::letEntityDoFooToMe()` to show you how methods of `World` can call methods of `Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make the method in the parent class virtual and override it in the entity class.

```
class World
{
public:
    virtual void Func();
}


class Entity: public World
{
public:
    void Func();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description my guess is that you are having some cyclic dependency problem. Have you tried to use #pragma once. Here is a reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768966/c-recursive-header-file-inclusion-problem). If you dont like that you could also try adding some ifndef in the headers for each.

```
// World.h
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H

// ... World declaration code goes here.

#endif

// Entity.h
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H

// ... Entity declaration code goes here.

#endif
```

Comment: I tried that right when I thought it might be a problem that the classes include each other, I still have the pragma once but neither of those fix the problem